# Frequency control of vibrator motor

Tags: motor, frequency, frequency-measurement, vibration, vibration-motor

I wish to generate a controllable frequency vibration on a device. The vibration frequency then has to be measured and filtered.
For this purpose, I am  using a vibrator motor as shown.

[image]

Now, i wish to genterate a vibration of frequency 5- 20 Hz but all I am able to get is a frequency greater than 30Hz.

I am controlling the motor by controlling the dc supply.

I tried using PWM and transistor circuit(as shown below), but that doesnt generate a single tone vibration but contains harmonics too, which i observed using labVIEW (may be due to nature of PWM)

[image]

I wish to generate a single tone vibration in the range 5-20Hz. How can I do it?
Does the sector angle of the CAM shaft have an effect on frequency of vibration?

Comment: Inserting a larger offset mass will slow the motor down to the ranges you want, but will wear out the brass bearing rather quickly.

Comment: "_I tried using PWM and transistor circuit, ..._" Show us the schematic. (There's a button on the editor toolbar.) "_... but that doesnt generate a single tone vibration but contains harmonics too._" How do you know? How did you measure this?

Comment: @Sparky256, would it decrease the frequency? if it does, does it depend on the mass only or also on the angle of shaft as well?

Comment: @transistor, i viewed the harmonics using labVIEW using accelerometer.

Comment: Your PWM frequency should be much greater than 20Hz for effective operation. You want to control the average speed of the motor such that it rotates at the speed that will create your desired vibrations (300 to 1200 RPM), so it would be desirable to have a PWM frequency greater than, say, 5kHz.

Comment: @user5089054. What do you mean by 'shaft-angle'? Or do you mean the tilt of the motor itself? With the motor spinning the wear on the bearing is constant per constant speed and offset mass.

Comment: @ user2943160,i did, i made pwm frequency 5khz, but have a vibration of around 100HZ despite having varied the duty cycle.

Comment: @Sparky256,here's a circular cam: http://www.linixmotor.com/8motor_spare/3_1.jpg   I am new so i couldnt post more than 2 pictures. So, in a vibrator motor, this isnt circular which can be seen from the pic of the motor posted above. what I mean is that, does the shape of the cam (circular, semicircular, quater circle) have an impact on frequency?

Comment: You may be SOL trying to get such low frequencies from a vibration motor. [These guys](https://www.precisionmicrodrives.com/tech-blog/2012/11/22/limits-of-vibration-frequency-for-miniature-vibration-motors) make them, and there's a lower limit to the vibration frequency that depends on several factors.  That link includes some background info (math) as well as info on the specific models that they make, so may be of some use in figuring out what you need to do and if it can be done at all.

Comment: [More info from the same site.](https://www.precisionmicrodrives.com/application-notes/ab-029-vibration-motors-voltage-vs-frequency-vs-amplitude)

Comment: Frequency is the same as motor speed.  The shape of the cam doesn't directly change that, but can have an indirect influence on motor speed.  Take an extreme case - make the cam have all of the mass 10cm from the axle.  The motor will have trouble accelerating the mass over that long arm, and may take a long time to reach full speed - or never reach it at all.

Comment: If you mount the motor with its shaft vertical, it may be able to start and run at lower speeds than other orientations. Horizontally it has to supply enough torque to lift the weight against gravity to start at all, at which point you are supplying enough voltage to run at 30Hz. By removing the gravity constraint it may be able to start and run at lower voltages, and therefore lower speeds.

Comment: You may need to adjust your PWM drive signal such that it gives the motor a little boost at startup (high-ish duty-cycle) and then once the motor has started, drop the PWM duty-cycle down to a much lower value to run the motor at a slow speed to get the low frequency you're looking for. Even so - 20Hz is very low for those tiny eccentric-mass vibration motors.

Comment: I believe it is possible to drive these motors at very low speeds using careful phasing and a tight feedback loop. You basically see the motor as a brushless DC motor, but one where the coils get switched around as it turns. You very carefully monitor the rotation (with an encoder or back emf) so that you can give a torque "kick" to the motor at exactly the right moments to keep it rotating at the desired speed. I've been meaning to do a project with this approach, so might be coaxed into getting something working. What is your application?

Comment: @bigjosh, I wish to stimulate an artificial tremor in the range of frequency of human tremor.

Comment: Are you required to use this motor? Could you potentially use a linear mass instead? This could be as cheap/simple as a magnet in  a soda straw wrapped with wire, and might better reproduce the tremor motion than an eccentric rotating weight.

Comment: @bigjosh , no i dont need to use a motor.. i just wish to generate a constant frequency vibration. How exactly do you mean?

Comment: You basically make a solenoid with a magnet that slides in and out of the coil. By driving the coil alternately in opposite directions, you can make the magnet move back and forth. One practical way to build one is to use a soda straw. Wind the wire in a coil around the middle of the straw and find a magnet that fits closely into the straw. If you can wait a week or two, I can make a prototype with detailed instructions.

Comment: Here is an example of driving a brushed DC motor at very low RPMs https://hackaday.io/project/9433-brushed-dc-servo-drive . He used an optical encoder for feedback, but you could likely get there using just back EMF for your purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Before even trying a modulation circuit to control the motor, see if it's possible at all.  Connect the motor to a variable supply and see if you can get the frequencies you want.  Quite possibly, you can't.

These motors often have significant cogging.  That means the magnetic field acts like detents along the way.  Such motors can't be run with a steady drive below the level where the toque doesn't overcome the detent force.  Once the drive does reach that level, the motor "breaks free" and runs fairly fast.  The detents are like little valleys, and once the motor runs they cause little average drag since the push down into the valley is about the same as the drag going back out of the valley.

Start at zero and slowly crank up the variable supply.  The motor will probably just sit there, then suddenly start spinning.  If that spinning speed is higher than the minimum you want, then you need a different motor.

Comment: Oh. It doesn't. Reaches around 20Hz but not below that. Can any manipulation to the motor shaft shape,size, weight cause the required effect?

Comment: @user: Once you get it going, more inertia on the shaft will allow you to keep it going at a lower speed, but won't be of help getting it started.  It sounds like this solution won't really work.  Step back two levels and explain (in a different question) what you really want to accomplish, and leave supposed solutions, like a vibrating motor, out of it.  A voice coil may be a solution, but again, we need to know what you ultimately want to do, not how you imagine solving the problem.